# Node MySQL Executing Queries Asyncronously

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have the following Node/Express route which is used to post data to a MySQL server. It first adds a new user to a table and then takes the id of the new user and adds some more info to a profile table. The second query is dependent on the first one so they run sequentially.

I have written the following code and it runs correctly and does the job.

```
routes.post('/register', (req,res) => {
  console.log('api req: ', req.body)
  const email = req.body.email
  const password = 'test'// req.body.password
  if (!email || !password) return res.status(400).json({type: 'error', message: 'Please provide email and password'})
  const hash = bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
  // console.log('hash is ...', hash )
  var sqlquery = "INSERT INTO user (username, first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES ('test@gmail.com', 'Dan', 'Brown', 'test@gmail.com', 'test')"

  db.query(sqlquery, (error, results) => {
    if (error) return res.status(400).json({type: 'error', message: error})
    if (results.length == 0) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // run another query based on results from previous query
      var profilequery = "INSERT INTO userprofile (user_id, address, age) VALUES (" + results.insertId + ", 'test address', 25)"
      db.query(profilequery, (error1, results1) => {
        if (error) return res.status(400).json({type: 'error1', message: error1})
        console.log("profile inserted, ID: " + results1)
      })
    }
    console.log("1 record inserted, ID: " + results.insertId);
    res.json({type: 'success', message: 'user registered', results})
    return results
  })
})
```

There are two problems:

**Problem 1:** This code is not asynchronous. I would love to use async/await on this code. Really appreciate if someone can help me convert this into async code.

**Problem 2:** I have tried to use bcrypt to hash the password. However, if I use the hashed value in the query, the query fails because bcrypt returns a promise and not the actual hashed password. I do I resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

not tested:

```
    asyncQuery = (query, args) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(query, function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

routes.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    console.log('api req: ', req.body)
    const email = req.body.email
    const password = 'test'// req.body.password
    if (!email || !password) return res.status(400).json({ type: 'error', message: 'Please provide email and password' })
    const hash = bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
    // console.log('hash is ...', hash )

    const sqlquery = "INSERT INTO user (username, first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES ('test@gmail.com', 'Dan', 'Brown', 'test@gmail.com', 'test')"

    let firstresult, secondresult;
    asyncQuery(sqlquery)
        .then(rows => {
            firstresult = rows;
            const profilequery = `INSERT INTO userprofile (user_id, address, age) VALUES ("${rows.insertId}", 'test address', 25)`;
            return asyncQuery(profilequery)
        })
        .then(rows => {
            secondresult = rows; 
        })
        .then( () => {
            console.log(`firstresult:${firstresult}`)
            console.log(`firstresult:${secondresult}`)

            res.json({ type: 'success', message: 'user registered', results })
        })
        .catch(rows => {
            console.log(`Error:${rows}`)
        })
})
```

Comment: This looks great and I am going to try it out. Is it also possible to use the async await syntax here?